# iOS - old local notifications pop when canceling other local notifications during performFetchWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilocalnotification

During `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` we are canceling local notifications that were set during previous runs of the app and setting updated ones.

```
 NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (UILocalNotification *notif in notifications) {
        if (/*some condition is met re the notif*/) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notif];
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
...
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

When the line of code for `cancelLocalNotification:notif` is called, another old local notification sometimes pop even though it has already popped by iOS in the past. Since I am not setting this notification as if iOS doesn't remember that it has already popped that notification.

It doesn't always happens, but we still didn't manage to figure out when this happens or the cause of this. Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**I just want to be clear that the strange issue I am seeing is that calling cancelLocalNotification for ANY notification sometimes causes other notification to pop. This happens only in rare cases when I had two notification set for the same time exactly.

Comment: By "pop" you mean remove-from-queue and not display-to-user?

Comment: Are the two snippets of code running concurrently?

Comment: Also, why don't you just call UIApplication:cancelAllLocalNotifications instead of the for-loop?

Comment: pop = the reminder is displayed to user. The two snippets don't run concurrently. Since now, I have not used cancelAllLocalNotifications because I have many items that should need a local notification and I wanted to set them once when the item is created without needing to go over all the items every time and create them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your app, but if it's possible, it's a lot easier for you to cancel all local notifications instead of looping through them. Write:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];`

If you only want to cancel a subset of all of the local notifications instead of all local notifications, I'd recommend:

- Canceling all local notifications
- Setting notifications again (include both notifications you didn't want to cancel, and new notifications that you want to set)

This is the simplest way of doing it since, by doing so, you don't have to store any references to the local notifications you've set in order to cancel a subset of notifications.

This is also helpful if you need to schedule more than 64 local notifications. Apple only allows for scheduling 64 local notifications at a time (the 64 local notifications with the earliest fire date). Queueing any subsequent local notifications are discarded. If you have designed your app such that it cancels all local notifications and enqueues relevant local notifications again, then the 64 local notification limit becomes less of an issue.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. For now, I am only creating notifications once without canceling them every time the app runs. This is to improve performance. Otherwise I need to go over thousands of items every time and figure out  which to assign a local notification. So I am basically creating a notification once. Still, I wonder why calling cancelLocalNotification: causes another local notification that was already displayed to pop. This is really strange.